# Make card float top of other cards when expanding on hover instead of pushing them down

Tags: html, css

I have a grid of cards and when I hover over one card the bottom section of this card expands to show more content.

The problem is that when it expands it pushes all other cards down. Instead, I would like it to layer itself on top of the card that is situated underneath. Here are some images to visualize what I'm talking about.

CodePen Example: https://codepen.io/adrenaline681/pen/qBMqrEy

As you can see here there is empty white space underneath:

[image: Wrong]

And here is an example of how I would like it to be. As you can see, the middle card has just expanded on top of the bottom card without pushing it down:

[image: Expected]

Here is how the CSS looks like:

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  width: 60%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  gap: 15px;
}

.card {
   transition: all 0.3s linear;
}

.card:hover {
  transform: scale(1.04)
}

.card:hover .description {
  max-height: 100px;
}
  
.image {
  aspect-ratio: 1.6;
  background-color: #516d9b;
  display: flex; 
  justify-content: center; 
  align-items: center;
}

.title {
  display: flex; 
  justify-content: center; 
  align-items: center;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #3f8539;
}

.description {
  transition: all 0.3s linear;
  display: flex; 
  justify-content: center; 
  align-items: center;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #c99753;
  padding-left: 25px;
}
```

Comment: Put your additional content in an absolute div within a .description div.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't care about keeping the transitions, the solution by Brett is simple and works.  If you do want the transitions, then you'll need a way to force the description panel to slide above its subsequent siblings.  To do that you can add z-index to the card that is hovered instead of the description.

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  gap: 1rem;
}

.card {
  position: relative;
  transition: transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.card:hover {
  transform: scale(1.04);
  /* push this card above siblings */
  z-index: 100;
}

.card:hover .description {
  max-height: 100%; /* set max-height to 100% */
  padding: 1rem; /* add the padding to top and bottom */
}
  
.image {
  aspect-ratio: 1.6;
  background-color: #516d9b;
}

.title {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #3f8539;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.description {
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-height: 0;
  height: max-content; /* dynamic height */
  background-color: #c99753;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  padding: 0 1rem; /* add padding left and right */
}


/* not important */

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  width: 60%;
  min-width: 30rem;
  max-width: 60rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.card > * {
  display: flex; 
  justify-content: center; 
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  user-select: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="image">Aspect ratio 1.6</div>
    <div class="title">Fixed height 100px</div>
    <div class="description">Dynamic height depending on content length. Dynamic height depending on content length.</div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="image">Aspect ratio 1.6</div>
    <div class="title">Fixed height 100px</div>
    <div class="description">Dynamic height depending on content length</div>
  </div> 
  <div class="card">
    <div class="image">Aspect ratio 1.6</div>
    <div class="title">Fixed height 100px</div>
    <div class="description">Dynamic height depending on content length</div>
  </div>  
  <div class="card">
    <div class="image">Aspect ratio 1.6</div>
    <div class="title">Fixed height 100px</div>
    <div class="description">Dynamic height depending on content length</div>
  </div>  
  <div class="card">
    <div class="image">Aspect ratio 1.6</div>
    <div class="title">Fixed height 100px</div>
    <div class="description">Dynamic height depending on content length</div>
  </div>  
  <div class="card">
    <div class="image">Aspect ratio 1.6</div>
    <div class="title">Fixed height 100px</div>
    <div class="description">Dynamic height depending on content length</div>
  </div>  
  <div class="card">
    <div class="image">Aspect ratio 1.6</div>
    <div class="title">Fixed height 100px</div>
    <div class="description">Dynamic height depending on content length</div>
  </div>  
  <div class="card">
    <div class="image">Aspect ratio 1.6</div>
    <div class="title">Fixed height 100px</div>
    <div class="description">Dynamic height depending on content length. Dynamic height depending on content length</div>
  </div>  
  <div class="card">
    <div class="image">Aspect ratio 1.6</div>
    <div class="title">Fixed height 100px</div>
    <div class="description">Dynamic height depending on content length</div>
  </div>  
  <div class="card">
    <div class="image">Aspect ratio 1.6</div>
    <div class="title">Fixed height 100px</div>
    <div class="description">Dynamic height depending on content length</div>
  </div>  
  <div class="card">
    <div class="image">Aspect ratio 1.6</div>
    <div class="title">Fixed height 100px</div>
    <div class="description">Dynamic height depending on content length</div>
  </div>  
  <div class="card">
    <div class="image">Aspect ratio 1.6</div>
    <div class="title">Fixed height 100px</div>
    <div class="description">Dynamic height depending on content length</div>
  </div> 
</div>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Aperiam, excepturi, aut, corporis sapiente molestias magnam nisi rem quo quos exercitationem temporibus repudiandae eveniet neque quidem veniam ipsum beatae? Consequatur, ex.</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

No need for Codepens here on Stack Overflow. We have snippets!

In this snippet I have made the adjustments to your code to implement the behaviour you are looking for.

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  width: 60%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  gap: 15px;
}

.card {
  position: relative;
}

.card:hover .description {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
}
  
.image {
  aspect-ratio: 1.6;
  background-color: #516d9b;
  display: flex; 
  justify-content: center; 
  align-items: center;
}

.title {
  display: flex; 
  justify-content: center; 
  align-items: center;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #3f8539;
}

.description {
  display: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #c99753;
  padding-left: 25px;
  z-index: 5;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="image">Aspect ratio 1.6</div>
    <div class="title">Fixed height 100px</div>
    <div class="description">Dynamic height depending on content length. Dynamic height depending on content length.</div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="image">Aspect ratio 1.6</div>
    <div class="title">Fixed height 100px</div>
    <div class="description">Dynamic height depending on content length</div>
  </div> 
  <div class="card">
    <div class="image">Aspect ratio 1.6</div>
    <div class="title">Fixed height 100px</div>
    <div class="description">Dynamic height depending on content length</div>
  </div>  
  <div class="card">
    <div class="image">Aspect ratio 1.6</div>
    <div class="title">Fixed height 100px</div>
    <div class="description">Dynamic height depending on content length</div>
  </div>  
  <div class="card">
    <div class="image">Aspect ratio 1.6</div>
    <div class="title">Fixed height 100px</div>
    <div class="description">Dynamic height depending on content length</div>
  </div>  
  <div class="card">
    <div class="image">Aspect ratio 1.6</div>
    <div class="title">Fixed height 100px</div>
    <div class="description">Dynamic height depending on content length</div>
  </div>  
  <div class="card">
    <div class="image">Aspect ratio 1.6</div>
    <div class="title">Fixed height 100px</div>
    <div class="description">Dynamic height depending on content length</div>
  </div>  
  <div class="card">
    <div class="image">Aspect ratio 1.6</div>
    <div class="title">Fixed height 100px</div>
    <div class="description">Dynamic height depending on content length. Dynamic height depending on content length</div>
  </div>  
  <div class="card">
    <div class="image">Aspect ratio 1.6</div>
    <div class="title">Fixed height 100px</div>
    <div class="description">Dynamic height depending on content length</div>
  </div>  
  <div class="card">
    <div class="image">Aspect ratio 1.6</div>
    <div class="title">Fixed height 100px</div>
    <div class="description">Dynamic height depending on content length</div>
  </div>  
  <div class="card">
    <div class="image">Aspect ratio 1.6</div>
    <div class="title">Fixed height 100px</div>
    <div class="description">Dynamic height depending on content length</div>
  </div>  
  <div class="card">
    <div class="image">Aspect ratio 1.6</div>
    <div class="title">Fixed height 100px</div>
    <div class="description">Dynamic height depending on content length</div>
  </div> 
    
</div>
```

Comment: This is a good example of a Stack Snippet, but it doesn't really answer the question. Is this OP's code copied verbatim into a Stack Snippet? Or is it an attempt at answering their question? If the latter, please edit it to explain what your large code snippet is doing and how it is different from OP's code.

Comment: My snippet does answer the OP's question, I just didn't think it necessary to explicitly say so. But I have edited my answer to explicitly say so.

Comment: @TylerH I also think closing the question was totally unnecessary. The information provided was perfectly adequate to understand the problem and provide a solution.

Comment: Your edit did nothing to explain your answer. Useful answers explain _explicitly_ what is wrong with OP's code. What did you change from OP's code? There's a lot of lines there; do you expect people to go through all of them and hunt, line by line, for what is changed? Providing code without explanation or comment is not particularly helpful, and is bad practice in general.

Comment: As for closing the question, questions asking for help with non-working code require a [mcve] in the question body, per the site rules. Reading the question body, I have no idea how OP's markup is structured because they did not include it.

Comment: @TylerH a minimal reproducible example is **recommended**, but it is not mandatory. Check the first paragraph of that article you linked to. Lack of a working example should not be automatic grounds for closing a question. If a question can still be interpreted and answered then it should remain open.

Comment: No, it _is_ mandatory. Questions also don't have to have _working_ examples (or else a question wouldn't need to be asked)... but they _do_ need to contain **all the code necessary to reproduce or help the OP**. All the solutions here may be invalid because they are may make assumptions based on what the markup is. You should also read the linked Meta post in that article: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/. Also read https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/149890/ and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/262126/ - tl;dr ***links to off-site code sandboxes are not sufficient on Stack Overflow.***